# Why do I get a NameError: name 'counter' is not defined, while I set the counter variable to global?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, counter, nameerror

Below is my code.  I don't know what I am doing wrong, but when I run this, I get NameError: name 'counter' is not defined. I'm learning Python from a textbook and according to the textbook my code is right. I can't find the difference between the textbook code and this code... I've seen other questions on stackoverflow about global variables, but I still can't figure out what I did wrong. Why do I get this error? And how to solve it?

UPDATE:
I know what I did wrong. I should write counter = 0 above the function.

```
def rpower(a, n):
    'returns a to the nth power'
    global counter          # counts number of multiplications

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    # if n > 0:
    tmp = rpower(a, n//2)

    if n%2 == 0:
        counter += 1
        return tmp*tmp      # 1 multiplication

    else:
        counter += 2
        return a*tmp*tmp    # 2 multiplications

print(rpower(2, 10000))
```

Comment: please fix indent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your `counter` variable is declared outside of you `function`. Like:

```
counter=0
def rpower(a, n):
    'returns a to the nth power'
    global counter          # counts number of multiplications

    if n == 0:
        return 1
    # if n > 0:
    tmp = rpower(a, n//2)

    if n%2 == 0:
        counter += 1
        return tmp*tmp      # 1 multiplication

    else:
        counter += 2
        return a*tmp*tmp    # 2 multiplications
print(rpower(2, 10000))
```

Comment: I didn't declare my counter outside my function. If i add counter = 0 outside my function, I don't get an error in IDLE and everything seems to be alright. However, if I run this code in Pycharm, I still get the NameError.

Comment: I have just ran this code in Pycharm, it worked without any error. Was your indentation correct?

Comment: The indentation was correct. I think it's counter=0 above the function that I didn't write that gave the error. Now it works in IDLE and Pycharm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite your code a little bit in PyCharm. Just changed the name of the function, because your code didn't worked by just ctrl+v:

```
def rpow(a, n):
global counter

if n == 0:
    return 1

tmp = rpow(a, n/2)

if n%2 == 0:
    counter += 1
    return tmp*tmp
else:
    counter += 2
    return a*tmp*tmp
```

print(rpow(2, 10000))

I don't got your error, but i reached `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Try to do the same.

Comment: If you write tmp = rpow(a, n//2) instead of tmp = rpow(a, n/2) you won't get the Recursion Error.

Comment: And that's because if you use n/2, n won't ever reach 0. If n never becomes 0, you will never get to the basecase ('if n == 0') and the function will never end. That's why you get the RecursionError. With n//2, n will reach 0 eventually, the base case runs and the function ends :)